# unable to cast to datarowview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

ITs Xaml code for DataGrid

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,30,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="149" Width="356" Name="orderGrid"   SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionChanged="orderGrid_SelectionChanged" />
```

Here is my  QUERY AND Item source

```
var orders = (from ss in db.electronics_orders
                      select new { ss.id,Date = ss.orderdate,Product_Title=ss.Electronic.Name, Quantity = ss.qty, TPrice = ss.qty * ss.unitprice}).ToList();
        orderGrid.ItemsSource = orders;
```

NOw i am trying to cast selected item to datarowview

```
 try
            {
                DataRowView grid = (DataRowView)orderGrid.CurrentItem;
            }
            catch (Exception e1) {
                MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
            }
```

But it shows Error

> Unable to cast object of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousType0`5[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]'
>   to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're selecting in the linq (`select new {ss.id,...}`) , you're basically getting a new internal anonymous class, which is NOT a `DataRow` , like it expects.
You'll have to either cast it, or use the object type that you're binding to so they'll be "compatible".